# how can you turn off airdrops on an erc115

Tags: solidity, remix, airdrop, erc

Just looking to see if anyone has come across the ability to stop airdrops on 1155?

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop an airdrop on a blockchain. You can make your wallet not to display it.